# std::async guarantee to run after return statement

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

What are some ways to execute a function asynchronously, but to have the guarantee that it will execute after returning from current function?

Example:

```
   std::future<void> future;
   int do_smth( std::function<void()> callback) 
   { 
       int id = 0;

       auto cb = [=](){ callback(id);};
       future = std::async(std::launch::async, cb);

       return id;
   }
```

The `std::async` call should execute after return was finished. ASFAIK that it's not guaranteed to happen, the execution might still happen before function returned.

[Edit] I want this so I can implement the observer pattern, like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    void send_request()
    {
        m_id = do_smth( std::bind(&A::on_result,this,_1);
    }

   void on_result(RequestId id) 
   {
      if (id == m_id) {
          // my request finished!
      }
   }
private:
   RequestId m_id;
};
```

I know I can use a thread, with a queue, and post events but was thinking there might something simpler, if I could use the `std::async`.

Comment: The obvious way is to create the thread in a suspended state and resume it after the function returned. There is currently no way to do that with standard C++, so you will need to do that in some other threading library.

Comment: Why do you want this behavior?

Comment: I'm having some strange feeling you are trying to implement async/await kind of ?thing

Answer (score 2):

Your example will block at the `std::async` call and wait for the async task to finish (so it is entirely synchronous).

To allow the task to continue running you need to store the returned future in a variable that outlives the function, e.g. by returning it from the function, or assigning it to some long-lived object outside the function:

```
std::future<void> some_global_future;

int do_smth( std::function<void()> callback) 
{ 
  int id = 0;

  some_global_future = std::async(std::launch::async, callback, id);

  return id;
}
```

Note there is no need to create a lambda as in your example. You can pass the callback and its argument directly to `std::async`, and they will be copied and passed to the new thread, equivalent to the `[=]` capture you used for the lambda.

Since you don't appear to use the `future` returned by `std::async` another option is to use a detached thread:

```
int do_smth( std::function<void()> callback) 
{ 
  int id = 0;

  std::thread(callback, id).detach();

  return id;
}
```

**Update:** to prevent the new thread running until the caller has exited you would need some synchronisation e.g.

```
std::mutex mx;

int do_smth( std::function<void()> callback) 
{ 
  int id = 0;
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mx);
  auto cb = [=]{ std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mx); callback(id); };
  std::thread(cb).detach();

  return id;
}
```

This ensures that `callback(id)` won't happen until the mutex can be locked, which means `do_smth` must have returned.

However, that does **not** mean that the assignment to `m_id` will have completed:

```
    m_id = do_smth( std::bind(&A::on_result,this,_1);
```

The OS scheduler could run `do_smth` then when it returns unlock the mutex, run the asynchronous thread, then when that finishes continue running the original thread and assign to `m_id`.

You will have a race condition here due to one thread assigning to `m_id` while the thread running the callback reads it. You need to set `m_id` inside `do_smth` to fix that.

Comment: So you mean you want to **prevent** the asynchronous function from even starting to run until after the caller returns?

Comment: Thanks, but if I pass the `id` as parameter(which I wanted to avoid), there's no need for locking with mutex. I guess I'll stick to that solution.